# How to ensure the background texture joins up smoothly around sphere in Three.js?

Tags: html, animation, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

[image: Image showing a visible line where the texture meets]

Below is the bit of the code which sets the texture and maps it onto a large sphere. I have tried all sorts of wrapping but the background is still not smooth as there is a clear joining where the two parts of the texture meets. How do I fix this? Is there a way to overlap the edges maybe?

```
var milkyWayTexture = loader.load('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/21/12/30/milky-way-1845068_1280.jpg');

 milkyWayTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; 
        milkyWayTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; 

        milkyWayTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        milkyWayTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

        // Create a large sphere mesh for the starry background
        var backgroundGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(900, 100, 100);
        backgroundGeometry.scale(-1, 1, 1); // Flip the geometry to invert the texture mapping

        var backgroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            side: THREE.DoubleSide, // Make the sphere visible from inside as well as outside
            map: milkyWayTexture // Add Milky Way texture
        });

        var backgroundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(backgroundGeometry, backgroundMaterial);
       
        scene.add(backgroundMesh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of [UV mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping). It defines how your texture will be projected on a 3D object.

Usually, on a sphere, if you simplify the concept to its core, it consists of a plane rotate in X and Y, to wrap on a sphere.
[image: UV mapping]

With the illustration you might have guess the solution:

- The earth is believed to be a sphere and a plane, and, illustrates exactly what you want to achieve, if you take a look at this website https://trinketmage.github.io/. It display [this earth "flat plane" (Equirectangular) texture](https://trinketmage.github.io/assets/map.png)  on a sphere.
- You need to look for `Equirectangular` mapping of the milky way texture ([example](https://hnsky.org/toast_pr)).
- It can also be achieve looking for `360 panorama` texture of milky way ([example](https://www.eso.org/public/france/images/eso0932a/?lang)).

Alternatively, to set an environment I think it's a better practice to use `scene.background` ([source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html#L55)) with a `EquirectangularReflectionMapping` texture from an HDR file (can be found [here](https://polyhaven.com/hdris/night)).